# Spectral flow of Dirac operator twisted by instanton

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, gauge-theory, index-theory, floer-homology, dirac-operator

Suppose $E$ is a $SU(2)$-bundle over a closed three manifold $M$ and $S$ is the spinor bundle over $M$. Also assume $D_{A(t)}:\Gamma(S\otimes_{\mathbb c} E)\to \Gamma(S\otimes_{\mathbb c} E)$ is  a family of Dirac operators twisted by a family of connections $A(t)$ on $E$, $t\in[0,1]$.

We have also a family of curl-div operators $L_{A(t)}:\Omega^0(E)\oplus\Omega^1(E)\to \Omega^0(E)\oplus\Omega^1(E)$ where 
\begin{equation}
L_{A(t)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&d^*_{A(t)}\\
d_{A(t)}&*d_{A(t)}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
My question is:

Suppose $A(0)$ and $A(1)$ are two **flat** connections and $\mathbb A:=\{A(t):t\in[0,1]\}$ is an **instanton** on $M\times[0,1]$.
Are there any relations between Spectral flow of $\{D_{A(t)}:t\in[0,1]\}$ and Spectral flow of $\{L_{A(t)}:t\in[0,1]\}$?

Note: From the work of Atiyah-Patodi-Singer we could relate them with expressions involving eta invariants and some characteristic classes. Are they getting simplified in our present situations? If the question above was not expressed properly, that's my fault. Please let me know, I would try to modify them.

Comment: Just for the record: If $A(0)$ is gauge-equivalent to $A(1)$, i.e. $\mathbb{A}$ is a closed loop in the configuration space modulo gauge, then $SF(L_t)=2SF(D_t)$ and this didn't need the path to be an instanton nor the endpoints to be flat.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for pointing out that. Is not Atiyah-Singer index theorem over $M\times S^1$ in that case imply $SF(L_t)=-8SF(D_t)$?

Comment: Yup, I hastily messed up the factor (because I'm coincidentally thinking about these operators twisted by other $U(2)$-bundles in my work).